# How to convert any string into a unique 6 or 8 digit code

Tags: python

So I am building a web application using Flask, where users can create a "family" and then actually invite their family members to join their group via a "code".

The person who creates the family has a choice to name their family anything. Now I need to convert that name to a 6 (or 8) digit code, which the family members can then enter to join.

I need a function that will convert a string, eg `"my family"` into a code.

Comment: Search for hashcode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 8 hex digits is okay for your purpose then you might use ADLER32 available in [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.adler32) built-in module as follow:

```
import zlib
def code(text):
    return "%08X" % zlib.adler32(text.encode())
print(code("my family"))
```

output

```
110F0389
```

Explantion: `zlib.adler32` requires bytes so text must be first `encode`d, then it is formated as 8 hex (`X`) digits. If value need less digits `0`s are prepended (you will always get 8 digits).